# Why is force zero when velocity is parallel to magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry

It doesn't makes sense to me that when charge is moving parallel to magnetic field, force on charge by magnetic field is zero I have done some research and can't find proper answer some people say that answer lies in Lorentz transformations and special relativity so why isn't charge experiencing force

Comment: Please indicate what research you have done, and explain why it doesn't make sense to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A B-field exerts force on a moving charge, in a direction perpendicular to the B field.   If the B field and the velocity of the charge are in the same direction, then there is no way to distinguish any single direction of the resulting
force (there's a 360 degree spread of perpendicular directions).  So, the only force vector that has no direction must be the correct answer (i.e. zero force).

A B-field exerts force on a moving charge, in a direction perpendicular to the motion of the charge.   By similar reasonong to above, this also means the
force must be zero when B and the velocity of the charge are parallel.

Comment: so how is charge still in motion when it is mowing parallel to magnetic field if there is zero force acting on them

Comment: A charge moving parallel to the B field is just ... coasting.    No acceleration.   An electron beam has a slight (conical) divergence, because electrons repel each other, SO if you have a nearly-parallel B field to the beam, the slight deflection pulls the beam apart, then (farther on) each electron completes its 'orbit' and the beam comes to a focus.   That's called magnetic focusing.

Answer (score 0):

You ask why this happens and I tell you how it happens. I suppose you know that an electron has the intrinsic properties of magnetic dipole moment and spin. This spin due to Einstein-de Haas-**experiment** behave like a gyroscope, if the axis of rotation and an external force are not coaxial a gyroscope moves perpendicular to both the axis and the force direction.

An external magnetic field in any way (stationary charge, non parallel or parallel to this field moving charge) will align the electrons magnetic dipole moment. In the case of stationary or parallel to the homogeneous magnetic field nothing more happens.

In the other case of non parallel moving charges the gyroscopic effect came into the game and deflect the particle which is equal to an acceleration of the particle. As we know an acceleration of electrons is accompanied with photon emission and this is indeed an observable fact. Since photon emission misalign the electrons magnetic dipole from the external field we get a cyclical process. The result is a spiral path (from tangerine slices).

Comment: can you please edit the second paragraph of your answer more and explain the answer more with mathematical relations